# Remove an item from cart

Tags: java, spring

I want to remove the item that is added to the cart. The cart will have the added items, with the delete button against each item.When i click the delete button, the item is not removed from cart.Cart loads with already added items.

**Controller code for delete**

```
@RequestMapping("deletefromcart.html")
    public ModelAndView removeFromCart(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
        Product requiredProduct = productService.getProductById(id);
        cart.removeItem(requiredProduct);
        return new ModelAndView("deletefromcart");
    }
```

**Cart.java**

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class Cart {

    private List<Product> shopping = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public void addItem(Product newItem)
    {
        this.shopping.add(newItem);
    }

    public void removeItem(Product newItem)
    {
        this.shopping.remove(newItem);
    }

    }
```

Comment: where is the `cart` instance for the particular user maintined, is it stored in `HttpSession` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue of object equality,which a List uses during remove() operation. I added equals() and hashcode(),(both override) to the product class.Now its working fine.